# Jquery is not loading in <ion-nav-view> templates in ionic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem while loading jquery library. I have two templates which are using jquery 2.0.0. When I add jquery 2.0.0 CDN in templates it's working fine, but when adding it in index.html locally it's not working.  And yes, adding jquery locally in template is not working. It's only working for CDN in template.

Please help me to understand how ion-nav-view serves jquery to templates.

Index.html:-

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
          <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title></title>
        <!--link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css"-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pure-min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grids-responsive.min.css">

          <script src="js/jquery/jquery2.0.js"></script>//here i added jquery locally.but its not loading in template.

     <body>


        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </body>
```

My Template:-

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>//here i am loding like this then its working but when adding locally like index.html its not working.....
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imageSliderReset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ImageSliderStyle.css">


<figure class="cd-image-container">
        <img src="{{imgFile}}" alt="Original Image">
        <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="original">Original</span>

        <div class="cd-resize-img"> <!-- the resizable image on top -->
            <img src="{{imageName}}" alt="Modified Image" >
            <span class="cd-image-label" data-type="modified">Modified</span>
        </div>

        <span class="cd-handle"></span>
    </figure> <!-- cd-image-container -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery with angular is anti pattern. DOM manipulation should be done in directives, but if you really need jQuery you should load it in index.html, not in templates